# After installing platformio from the official guide on Clion, I have a problem with No module named 'platformio'

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, clion, platformio

After installing platformio from the official guide on Clion, I have the following problem:

```
 File "/opt/platformio/penv/bin/pio", line 5, in <module>
    from platformio.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'platformio'
```

I tried adding Path, and also reinstalling. But that didn't help either. Whenever I try to initialize the project, it crashes with an error.

I'm trying to run this on Clion, my operating system is Fedora 38. [image]

Comment: Include a link to the instructions you followed so we know exactly what you did. `ModuleNotFoundError` is AFAIK a Python diagnostic, but you have tagged C++.  Have you looked at third party guides? This https://johetajava.hu/en/post/platform-io-clion author, suggests the "official" instructions are incomplete or out of date and describes his successful setup process.

Comment: I marked C++ because I use CLion, and this IDE is designed for them. I've already found the problem. It sounds like this. I was installing CLion from the Sofware application in Fedora. From there, you can only install the flat package. The problem was that after installation, clion didn't have extended rights to search for installed libraries and plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the problem. It sounds like this. I was installing CLion from the Sofware application in Fedora. From there, you can only install the flat package. The problem was that after installation, clion didn't have extended rights to search for installed libraries and plugins. Therefore, you need to write the path to the directory where the script is stored yourself.  The problem can be solved in several ways.

The first way is to uninstall the flat package and install it yourself through the official portal.

The second way is to extend the rights of Clion.

The third way is to install platformio directly into the CLion interpreter.